# New to spark/pyspark Memory and conf issues

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, memory, config

I'm new to Spark and just got it set up on a local machine. Sadly I'm only able to run spark on 1 machine and no other computers at the moment.

I'm running the FPGrowth algorithm on a fairly large data set and I'm running into a few issues.

So far, the spark algorithms are pretty straightforward but the System Management component is pretty confusing to me

1. I get the following warning "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\context.py:125: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead."

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when I initialize spark I use the following code
`spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("new").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()`

I dont adjust any of the conf settings in pyspark. All of that is done in the spark-defaults.conf file

2. Sometimes the above error doesnt occur and I get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: JavaHeapSpace error when I try to get the FPGrowth rules
   I have the driver and executor memory settings pretty high in the spark-defaults.conf file

```
spark.driver.memory                100g
spark.executor.memory              200g
```

I have about 1TB of Disk space, its my understanding that spark will use disk space in addition to ram, but documentation on spark hasnt really been helpful.

I know I'm probably missing a lot of understanding/information. So, any direction on how to get this task accomplished is helpful